# WampServer status icons are difficult to distinguish for colorblind individuals (~7% of users)

Tags: user-interface, wamp, wampserver, color-blindness

I'm a computer engineer with deuteranomaly (green-weak vision). WampServer's displays an orange icon when some services are running, which violates usability/accessibility guidelines because it's difficult to differentiate from the green and red icons, and the only difference between the icons is the color. This means I need to lean in close to the monitor and/or hover over the icon to tell what's going on, which is rather annoying. How can I make these icons more clear?

---

About 1/12 men are color deficient, and about 90% of software developers are male, so this poor color choice impacts about 7% of WampServer's users.

Status icons should follow best practices and use a clear high-contrast scheme that spans the spectrum (ex: blue, yellow, red) and incorporates symbols instead of relying solely on color. Why limit colors to the most problematic ~50 nm range of wavelengths when you've got ~300 nm to work with? Moreover, the human brain is highly sensitive to shapes - effective user interfaces don't rely solely on color. Plus, some developers may alter their monitor's color gamut either directly or by using an app like f.lux.

For anyone who's unfamiliar with the human eye, here's a graph of [human cone cell spectral sensitivities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc9JP.png) showing how close the medium- and long-wavelength cones' peaks are. Dichromats must find this extremely frustrating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in User Experience Stack Exchange

Answer (score -1):

The icons WampServer uses are contained within a bitmap file called images_off.bmp, which you can find in the wamp or wamp64 folder.

I have attached a [modified version of images_off.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXhAa.png) that adds white/gray symbols above the point of the W - an X, a triangle, and a checkmark. Simply replace the file (backing up the original if desired) and close and reopen the program.

I encourage anyone who's involved with UI decisions to read up on best practices and use better color and symbolic choices, as bad decisions can severely impact the usability of products.